# Stuck over a problem in electrostatics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

I am stuck over an apparently simple problem that reads:

> Consider the system in the figure below. An internal sphere of radius $r_1 = R$ is surrounded by two spherical shells or radii $r_2 = 2R$ and $r_3 = 3R$. The internal sphere contains a volumetric charge density $\rho_1$, uniform. The internal shell contains a volumetric charge density
> $$\rho_2(r) = \dfrac{k}{r}$$ where $k$ is a constant.
>
> The external shell is a conductor, electrically neutral.
> The Electric field outside the whole system is zero. Calculate the expression of the density $\rho_1$ in terms of $R$ and $k$.

I am stuck over this for since it does say the volumetric density $\rho$ is uniform, how can it depend on $R$?

I know that

$$Q = \rho V$$
Where $V$ is the volume, but since $\rho$ is uniform my only guess is
$$\rho = \dfrac{Q}{\dfrac{4}{3}\pi R^3}$$
But there is no $k$ here...

[image]

Comment: Where is "the figure below"? Would be helpful for understanding the question. Or, alternatively, a more accurate description of the problem. Is it right to assume that the first spherical shell has outer radius $2R$ and inner radius $R$?

Comment: @kricheli I added a picture that should work for the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's use Gauß's law in integral form for a volume that contains the whole system (e.g. a sphere of radius $4R$). Since the electric field on the surface - and thus also the surface integral over the field - is zero, we find that the charge of the whole system is zero.
$$Q=\rho V$$
is valid for constant charge density. More generally the charge is a volume integral
$$Q=\int \rho \,\text{d}V$$
and for a spherically symmetric charge density
$$Q=4 \pi \int \rho(r) r^2 \,\text{d}r\,.$$
Now that we already know that the outer shell is electrically neutral we have the total charge
$$Q=4\pi \int_0^R \rho_1(r) r^2\,\text{d}r + 4\pi \int_R^{2R} \rho_2(r) r^2\,\text{d}r\,.$$
The rest is simple. ;)